# Escaping string and then adding html tags in jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a string I want to escape and then add only specific html tags before printing it in jinja. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
{{ user.info | e | nl2br | safe  }}
```

So essentially I want to convert new lines to `<br/>` but escape every html tag provided by user. This doesn't seem to work, the `<br/>` tags are also getting escaped. How can I achieve such behavior in Jinja?

Comment: If you remove the `| safe` filter - `{{ user.info | e | nl2br  }}` does it works?

Comment: no, it gives me same results. Apparently the safe and escape do not work in the same context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution, it seems that escape actually returns a Markup object, so calling safe on it doesn't help. I had to define a custom filter:

```
@app.template_filter('escape_custom')
def escape_custom(string):
    string = str(jinja2.escape(string))
    return jinja2.Markup(string.replace('\n', '<br/>\n'))
```